# Does Sonatype's Nexus Repository offer any benefit with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus, sonatype

So I'm setting up a CI solution using Jenkins and I've been instructed to use SonaType's Nexus Repository as a binary repository that ties into Jenkins. The idea as I understand is that it will provide immediate rollback to previous compiled binaries.

Some of the other engineers who have experience with Jenkins have questioned this decision, because they believe Jenkins can already do this. Apparently Jenkins will store build results for immediate rollback deployment anyway, so the inclusion of Nexus is of dubious benefit.

Is it true that Jenkins can already offer immediate rollback without a third-party service or plugin? If so, what is the benefit of using Nexus with Jenkins if any?

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of use an artifact repository (Nexus, Jfrog Artifactory..) with Jenkins(or another CI tool like Bamboo) is that you can deploy your artifacts to a repository in Nexus(or Artifactory) with their control version (include SNAPSHOT in maven) previously to send these artifacts to each environment (integration environment, production environment...).

This is a good practice because when you do an install of your projects, for example:

```
mvn install
```

Your projects downloads all dependencies from the artifact repository (Nexus, Artifactory...) and theses dependencies are organized and availables for al your team.